# Does a switch have an address, if it is un-configured?

Tags: switch

Does a switch have an address, if it is un-configured ?
If all the ports are connected to devices with static IP addresses and the switch is un-configured, will the switch have an IP address ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

An address is part of the configuration, so if you have not configured the switch, it will not have an address. Even if the network has DHCP, you would need to configure the switch to use DHCP.

The Cisco 2960 can have addresses on the physical interfaces (requires the correct license), but normally has addressing on SVIs. If you did not configure it, then you don't have any SVIs.

Comment: Thanks Ron. So by default No IP address or subnet mask are defined and No default gateway is defined.

Comment: Correct. You would need to do some type of configuration to have any of that.